# How to build a project for publishing it in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just finished my project. I want my friends to test it too, so I want to share. How can I do it? Probably not just taking main.py and send it to people right?

I used to create projects with Java using Intellij IDEA, and in that IDE, there is a button like "Build Project" and when you press it, IDE builds the project and creates the folder. Is It same in Pycharm too?

Thanks much.

Comment: Yes sir.thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send him everything just like you have on your hard disk except the `venv` folder. That is:

- Python files (*.py)
- resources files (graphics and sound)
- config files
- ...

And for the libraries, create a `requirements.txt` file so he can create a virtual environment and install whatever libraries are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a compiled language. The Build Project button creates a JAR file that you can send to your friends.

Unlike Java, Python is an interepreted language. You can send the `main.py` file to your friends, but they will also need to install Paython on their computer.